# How do I specify an objects type when Key is a known value?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, how would I define the type of object `data` when `data.type` is a known value?

In the below example, I would like `data` to be typed accordingly when `data.type` is either `"sms"` or `"email"`

```
const payload = '{"type":"sms","destination":123}'

type PayloadType = 'sms' | 'email'

interface BasePayload {
    type: PayloadType
}

interface SmsPayload extends BasePayload {
    destination: number
}

interface EmailPayload extends BasePayload {
    destination: string
}

const data: SmsPayload | EmailPayload = JSON.parse(payload)
```

TIA

*PS: I know phone numbers aren't numbers... this is just an example.

Comment: I assume you're asking, after it is parsed, how does one differentiate between `SmsPayload` and `EmailPayload`?  The answer is you need to look at the value `sms` or `email` and then cast it to the type, such as with `as`.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I know with function args (from one of my previous questions), you can map the types with this sort of syntax `{ [K in TemplateTypes]: [K, EntityMap[K]] }[TemplateTypes]`, but was hoping there would be some sort of magic for doing the same here, whereby I could get the value and map it to a type at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to leave inheritance behind sometimes, but here it isn't necessary.

Just create two types with a common discriminating field, `type`:

```
interface SmsPayload {
    type: 'sms'
    destination: number
}

interface EmailPayload {
    type: 'email'
    destination: string
}
```

create a union type from these:

```
type PayloadUnion = EmailPayload | SmsPayload
```

now, you can:

```
const data: PayloadUnion = JSON.parse(payload) // trusting the backend here
```

and narrow using the common discriminator field

```
if (data.type === 'sms'){
    // in here `data` is of type SmsPayload
}
```

Comment: I completely overlooked this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your example as it is, both `{"type":"sms","destination":123}` and `{"type":"email","destination":123}` have type `SmsPayload`.

So first modify interface definitions to get rid of this overlap:

```js
const payload = '{"type":"sms","destination":123}';

type PayloadType = "sms" | "email";

interface BasePayload {
  type: PayloadType;
}

interface SmsPayload extends BasePayload {
  type: "sms";
  destination: number;
}

interface EmailPayload extends BasePayload {
  type: "email";
  destination: string;
}
```

Now you only need to check `type` key:

```js
const data: SmsPayload | EmailPayload = JSON.parse(payload);

if (data.type === "email") {
  const email = data; // vscode for me infers type email: EmailPayload.
}
```

Note that this assumes that `payload` string is welformed. Typescript for example won't notice if you make a mistake and give string destination to sms: `const payload = '{"type":"sms","destination":"123"}';`. This is because your code runs at runtime, while typescript is checking your code at compile time - it doesn't have enough information to spot this error.

For runtime validation I warmly recommend library [zod](https://zod.dev/).